# Send an e-mail notification to custom user role when a file is uploaded to uploads folder

Tags: uploads, hooks, actions

I have written a custom php that allows a user from my templated page from the front end to upload files in a newly created subfolder which takes **user_login** as its name within the **uploads** folder. So the root folder is uploads and inside the user's subfolder are stored all the files. This is my code.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="POST" class="centered">   

<p></p>

<p>
Select a document to upload
</p>

<?php 


$user = wp_get_current_user();

$dirname = $user->user_login;

$upload_dir   = wp_upload_dir();
// creates a user subdir for the files
if ( isset( $current_user->user_login ) && ! empty( $upload_dir['basedir'] ) ) {
    $user_dirname = $upload_dir['basedir'].'/'.$current_user->user_login;
        if ( ! file_exists( $user_dirname ) ) {
        wp_mkdir_p( $user_dirname );
    }
}


if(isset($_FILES['document'])){

$errors = array();

$document = $_FILES['document']['name'];
$file_tmp = $_FILES['document']['tmp_name'];

if(empty($errors)==true){
         move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"/$user_dirname/".$document);
         echo "The file was uploaded successfully!";
      }else{
         print_r($errors);
      }

}

?>


<input type="file" name="document" class="centered" value="">
<p></p>
<input type="submit" value="Upload Document" name="submit">

</form>
```

As you can see I haven't used any of the WP functionality, because I am not very experienced, but I would like to create an **action** (I believe this is the right word) that sends email notifications every time a file is uploaded to the uploads folder. What hook do I need to use and/or in what way do I need to modify my code to be able to user the wordpress actions?

I have found this action [publish_post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/publish_post) that provides an example on how to send an e-mail when a post is created. However my code doesn't create a post and it wouldn't work in a case where I have a batch program doing the uploads. Is there an action that triggers when a file is uploaded that I could use?

My background is Laravel, so I'm still learning the WP ways of doing things and using mainly PHP with limited use of WP functionalities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the wp_mail function https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/ to send an email to anyone after the file is successfully uploaded in your directory. You do not need any action here

Add  it your code after the file is uploaded successfully

```
if(empty($errors)==true){
         move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"/$user_dirname/".$document);
         echo "The file was uploaded successfully!";
         wp_mail(..);
      }else{
         print_r($errors);
      }

}
```

Comment: Could I do that by inserting it inside my code that uploads the file?

Comment: Do I need to configure SMTP? Because I am certain the code I have written is functional, but I am not receiving any e-mails.

Comment: Found an answer here https://www.flippercode.com/send-html-emails-using-wp-mail-wordpress/ looks like you will have to add phpmailer_init action